# Input and options

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Hello friends I want to create a special numeric range for the input type number one, depending on the tag. That is, by selecting any of the options, this numerical range will change! For example, if you select option 2, min = 10 and max = 25 in input. While if you choose option 3, the min is = 5 and the max is 45 in input. Is such a thing possible? How can such be. Created the feature with the help of js or php?

```
<select id="selbox">
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
    <option value="option3">option3</option>
    <option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>

<input type="number"name ="num"id="num">
```

Comment: If you want this to happen immediately, it must be done in JavaScript. PHP doesn't run until the form is submitted, so it can't change client-side attributes.

Comment: Yes we can do this with JS, PHP is server-side. Check `change` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event . You need to know what selectors are and how to use it ( examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/w3js/w3js_selectors.asp ).

Answer (score 1):

Use an object with same keys as the values of your `<select>`. Then you can reference the particular range simply in a change event listener and set the appropriate min/max

```js
const ranges = {
  option1: {min: 10, max: 25}, 
  option2: {min: 5, max: 30},
  option3: {min: 100, max: 200}
}

document.getElementById('selbox').addEventListener('click', function(e){
   const {min, max} = ranges[this.value],
         input = document.getElementById('num');
   input.value ='';
   input.min = min;
   input.max = max;
});
```

```html
<select id="selbox">
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>

<input type="number" name="num" id="num">
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged `JQuery`, so I'll gear my answer towards that, but this is a pretty basic use case of a [dynamic frontend](https://wpamelia.com/static-vs-dynamic-website/#:%7E:text=Static%20websites%20are%20ones%20that,databases%20in%20addition%20to%20HTML.) so I'm going to outright code it. The basic flow for this is to have selecting an option trigger the change of a variable, which is then reflected on the input element. That change in data is normally referred to as the `state` or `client-side state` of the app.

Anyways, attach an onChange callback to the `select`, then set the value for the input.
Something like

```
$("select").change(function (e){ 
...set the variable here...
...set range for the input here...
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set a min and max with JavaScript on the input.

What you have to do is to listen for change on the select and depending on that value you will set the min and max values.

```
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_number_min.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_number_max.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp
```

Comment: Don't put links in a code block, they aren't clickable.