# Input and a select box

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to have a dependent numeric input.

This numeric input depends on a select box that creates a specific numeric range for the input by selecting each option.

For example:

if we select option2, the numeric input will be min = 20 and max = 50!,
if we select option3, the numeric input will be min = 10 and max = 30!.
How can such a feature be created?

Here's what I've tried:

```
<form>
    <select id="selbox">
        <option value="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" id="num">
    <button>click</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Hello Mohsen, welcome to Stack Overflow! You provided your HTML structure, but is there also JavaScript code that you tried out in order to achieve your goal?

Comment: Hi @mohsen, you seem to be a relatively new member of SO. Please try and keep your questions as clear and structured as possible. And please do not ask the same (or very similar) question several times (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146910/dependent-input) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67132782/input-and-options)). This is not helpful. Instead try and elaborate `one` question further and guide us to the point where you seem to have the problem. Let us know why @Charlietfl's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67132924/2610061) did not work for you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dependent input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146910/dependent-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in JavaScript by adding a change EventListener to the `select` tag which will help you extract the range values selected. Then you set those as `min` and `max` attributes for the `input`.

```js
const select = document.querySelector("#selbox");
const textBox = document.querySelector("#num");

select.addEventListener("change", setRangeForInput);

function setRangeForInput() {
  const [rangeMin, rangeMax] = select.value.split('-'); //this is ES6 destructuring syntax
  textBox.setAttribute("min", rangeMin);
  textBox.setAttribute("max", rangeMax);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select id="selbox">
    <option value="20-40">option1</option>
    <option value="30-50">option2</option>
    <option value="3-7">option3</option>
  </select>

  <input type="number" id="num">
  <button>click</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is good idea to using libraries that allow you to display fields depending on the selection of others: [dependsOn](https://dstreet.github.io/dependsOn/)